# making scanned pdf

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i need to convert bulk of pdf documents into non-editable format(scanned) some one help me to achieve this using C#.net

Comment: By "scanned", do you mean you're trying to convert them into images?

Comment: yes i need to convert into tiff images and again i need to convert tiff images into non-searchable pdf document

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Chris's comment is correct and you're trying to convert PDF docs to pictures, I'd suggest taking a look at [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) which is a .Net wrapper around [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which is an open source library for doing things like that.

Never used it myself, but it looks interesting.